# Django Multitenant - Populate connection list using default database

Tags: mysql, django, database

I have a Django Project with multitenant. Each client has is own database.
I want to create a table in the `default` database containing the client. Something like this:

```py
class Tenant(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I want to use this model so that I can populate `DATABASES` setting or django `connections` and to avoid writing more code.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think you gotta do way more than this, i'm not sure if i undrestood the problem correct here, so you want to have a model for all the database instances? and keep the data of those for example psql databases in this model?

Comment: Yes a db table with all databases names insideof it so I can populate databse connection list using the this table. I am trying something I will share more if it works.